# MVC WebGrid - Set Column Width

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, styling, webgrid

I'm trying to set the width of a column in an MVC WebGrid (last column) but despite applying a class within the grid.column declaration (shown in the code below), the width does not change.

The class is successfully applied in the html, but only to the rows within the  section though and not the column header cell within the  section.  At first I thought this was the reason that the width did not change in the browser but I then added the class to the header cell in the browser (using dev tools) and it still didn't change the width.

```
  @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid",                              
    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",                           
    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",                          
    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",                         
    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",                           
    rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
    columns: grid.Columns(                                                                       
      grid.Column("Source", header: "source"),                                                                      
      grid.Column("Note", header: "note"),                                                                      
      grid.Column("Created", header: "created", format: @<text>@item.Created.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm")</text>),                                                                     
      grid.Column("Data", header: "data", canSort: true, style: "dataColWidthStyle")                                                                       
    )
   )
```

Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width of columns in CSS.

Dont forget to set width for `<th>` tags in `<thead>` instead `<td>` tags of `<tbody>` when you are using table header.